# time series decomposition - remove seasonality

Tags: time-series

I have some time series data and I apply the `decompose` function in R to obtain the following output.

[image]

I remove the seasonality by running the following: `orig - decomp$seasonal`

My question is, what data should I take away from this plot? Say I have a multivariate time series problem. Say I am trying to predict Passenger demand at airport X, but I also use as input the time series passenger demand from airport Y and Z. So in order to predict X I feed in Y and Z time series also. Each airports demand has a seasonal pattern which I need to correct for.

I should decompose the seasonality from all X, Y, Z airports and then in order to predict X I should give as inputs the removed seasonality from Y and Z? or should I give the model all of the decomposed components - seasonality, trend and random...

Second after removing the seasonality in the plot the `random` part still (to me) seems to have some "information" or seasonality… That is, it doesn't look completely "random".

What can I do here?

```
Data <- structure(c(47.9917001781891, 47.9261938741777, 47.8606875701671, 
47.7951812661564, 47.7296749621457, 47.664168658135, 47.5986623541244, 
47.5331560501137, 47.467649746103, 47.4021434420923, 47.3366371380817, 
47.271130834071, 47.2056245300603, 47.1401182260496, 47.0746119220389, 
47.0091056180283, 46.9435993140176, 46.8780930100069, 48, 21, 
159, 179, 75, 29, 34, 38, 46, 101, 116, 9, 7, 71, 115, 123, 86, 
10, 27, 73, 42, 21, 56, 30, 38, 24, 35, 65, 100, 14, 51, 21, 
15, 43, 19, 19, 8, 24, 44, 34, 12, 23, 33, 27, 74, 36, 30, 16, 
20, 38, 31, 43, 28, 45, 21, 97, 77, 68, 69, 62, 47, 27, 52, 71, 
22, 17, 10, 16, 29, 39, 9, 7, 8, 15, 7, 11, 22, 26, 14, 24, 21, 
13, 14, 18, 23, 41, 32, 27, 18, 14, 42, 53, 32, 15, 38, 34, 49, 
52, 30, 21, 15, 22, 7, 9, 14, 13, 13, 22, 19, 11, 9, 11, 26, 
9, 17, 14, 8, 12, 28, 22, 22, 35, 47, 35, 13, 10, 8, 8, 20, 18, 
18, 15, 24, 23, 27, 11, 29, 21, 14, 12, 12, 20, 17, 11, 20, 19, 
31, 21, 36, 35, 34, 10, 10, 34, 35, 52, 46, 30, 16, 14, 21, 18, 
41, 35, 43, 11, 31, 24, 52, 31, 61, 39, 55, 29, 18, 23, 12, 35, 
45, 51, 46, 54, 25, 15, 21, 25, 10, 8, 19, 47, 24, 26, 35, 41, 
15, 33, 18, 15, 18, 43, 40, 40, 22, 22.7180322515486, 21.3603199781131, 
20.0026077046776, 18.6448954312422, 17.2871831578067, 15.9294708843712, 
14.5717586109357, 12, 19, 24, 53, 41, 17, 20, 16, 64, 63, 20, 
24, 15, 24, 58, 19, 24, 37, 61, 57, 33, 8, 8, 38, 74, 56, 62, 
55, 63, 94, 23, 29, 17, 39, 37, 61, 61, 42, 11, 15, 30, 34, 55, 
61, 55, 87, 70, 35, 12, 67, 90, 36, 53, 29, 14, 53, 18, 40, 57, 
64, 47, 18, 95, 115, 141, 144, 138, 102, 56, 89.4059169426189, 
106, 188, 206, 110, 14, 8, 18, 110, 152, 147, 149, 105, 25, 12, 
7, 17, 58, 158, 87, 28, 15, 120, 25, 57, 93, 15, 9, 25, 133, 
129, 114, 90, 60, 101, 103, 59, 23, 42, 39, 72, 60.1559708435794, 
53.4295208592592, 46.703070874939, 29, 108, 109, 111, 155, 192, 
109, 47, 101, 182, 142, 37, 57, 79, 47, 35, 28, 55, 81, 174, 
188, 175, 145, 66, 36, 81, 100, 28, 62, 27, 32, 33, 32, 37, 19, 
176, 218, 205, 153, 119, 124, 194, 167, 123, 41, 41, 42, 123, 
124, 134, 72, 27, 21, 40, 73, 82, 192, 165, 166, 122, 135, 177, 
189, 150, 154, 171, 68, 37, 20, 27, 26, 16, 48, 33, 16, 19, 12, 
108, 117, 112, 80, 21, 21, 30, 32, 54, 44, 61, 50, 48, 23, 31, 
66, 66, 22, 17, 28, 12, 14, 48, 65, 47, 89, 31, 17, 36, 40, 44, 
24, 6, 11, 12, 13, 71, 99, 69, 45, 49, 61, 56, 103, 102, 34, 
20, 24, 35, 72, 56, 26, 12, 10, 21, 13, 15, 9, 9, 14, 12, 20, 
19, 29, 24, 20, 13, 13, 19, 21, 35, 41, 15, 13, 31, 50, 28, 31, 
39, 23, 23, 16, 29, 23, 31, 26, 43, 16, 18, 22, 46, 47, 27, 20, 
20, 8, 17, 25, 21, 21, 22, 21, 15, 18, 20, 21, 28, 17, 30, 17, 
23, 28, 42, 28, 21, 8, 39, 29, 26, 18, 22, 34, 42, 34, 19, 33, 
21, 27, 18, 32, 18, 12, 22, 15, 20, 20, 19.1838237454693, 18.5300050966337, 
17.876186447798, 17.2223677989624, 16, 18, 34, 19, 5, 17, 11, 
17, 13.8418813149188, 11.6783309466219, 9, 10, 13, 27, 28, 20, 
18, 10, 9, 17, 10, 31, 24, 29, 13, 7, 18, 26, 26, 38, 25, 13, 
14, 36, 59, 28, 44, 27, 16, 10, 9, 18, 21, 31, 8, 16, 13, 44, 
30, 18, 38, 12, 14, 11, 54, 56, 83, 119, 62, 37, 12, 75, 85, 
42, 85, 33, 24, 8, 61, 64, 107, 103, 46, 12, 50, 70, 86, 88, 
65, 77, 17, 25, 83, 108, 121, 82, 49, 28, 61, 96, 150, 111, 166, 
132, 94, 67, 91, 126, 81, 31, 95, 83, 26, 38, 19, 45, 40, 62, 
59, 85, 79, 76, 39, 39, 36, 15, 22, 117, 115, 58, 94, 129, 64, 
14, 31, 58, 71, 104, 47, 22, 44, 51, 50, 49, 103, 153, 114, 128, 
168, 175, 196, 143, 31, 146, 90, 112, 53, 125, 226, 165, 73, 
32, 35, 15, 13, 32, 10, 11, 31, 111, 211, 371, 278, 239, 77, 
134, 189, 191, 172, 142, 156, 176, 112, 13, 157, 210, 240, 138, 
134, 124, 182, 121, 131.029548800929, 127, 192, 138, 103, 35, 
64, 159, 189, 125, 108, 116, 108, 141, 172, 219, 61, 22, 44, 
121, 118, 86, 56.5910617580181, 24, 15, 35, 74, 42, 53, 63, 86, 
42, 37, 65, 44, 74, 61, 90, 58, 33, 76, 132, 114, 144, 153, 96, 
57, 86, 121, 71, 43, 17, 11, 27, 37, 51, 73, 56, 26, 52, 79, 
118, 112, 97, 22, 16, 6, 14, 25, 33, 100, 62, 48, 76, 54, 54, 
38, 36, 83, 60, 29, 28, 22, 24, 14, 7, 13, 55, 49, 17, 9, 25, 
11, 7, 6, 17, 53, 8, 12, 9, 9, 7, 9, 10, 13, 14, 23, 7, 10, 15, 
17, 41, 58, 20, 13, 10, 27, 19, 82, 72, 59, 35, 19, 12, 9, 46, 
20, 17, 8, 14, 12, 14, 40, 55, 26, 6, 17.8830069661194, 28, 16, 
36, 43, 38, 16, 5, 22, 14, 17, 15, 11, 12, 7, 7, 9, 30, 21, 15, 
19, 12, 37, 23, 22, 15, 29, 45, 35, 61, 86, 81, 29, 12, 5, 6, 
42, 35, 11, 8, 19, 16, 9, 24, 13, 19, 21, 47, 7, 11, 40, 58, 
50, 36, 46, 9, 9, 45, 18, 21, 17, 14, 7, 20, 37, 39, 30, 24, 
21, 10, 7, 29, 13, 68, 83, 109, 37, 8, 19, 18, 5, 29, 54, 69, 
49, 89, 40, 30, 43, 17, 5, 32, 21, 38, 31, 21, 16, 10, 9, 16, 
24, 39, 68, 79, 27, 12, 33, 75, 42, 23, 41, 89, 77, 102, 102, 
22, 28, 42, 62, 50, 7, 11, 28, 46, 57, 24, 40, 79, 92, 115, 103, 
127, 56, 76, 71, 105, 59, 16, 22, 22, 12, 47, 103, 106, 76, 24, 
25, 42, 122, 141, 96, 47, 35, 24, 22, 107, 79, 51, 12, 26, 40, 
38, 25, 44, 49, 92, 35, 11, 15, 52, 73, 69, 84, 61, 41, 45, 118, 
108, 113, 120, 134, 123, 103, 32, 26, 26, 45, 34, 64, 134, 151, 
42, 12, 93, 64, 73, 102, 198, 172, 185, 146, 22, 6, 6, 31, 76, 
100, 31, 27, 46, 72, 133, 67, 116, 177, 235, 109, 48, 57, 77, 
146, 120, 202, 178, 163, 73, 76, 68, 109, 43, 23, 8, 21, 12, 
9, 17, 8, 8, 6, 13, 20, 8, 15, 56, 64, 54, 54, 177, 170, 195, 
84, 9, 43, 163, 84, 9, 20, 23, 16, 21, 9, 10, 95, 175, 134, 114, 
56, 48, 30, 28, 21, 11, 23, 32, 52, 52, 31, 25, 33, 44, 11, 22, 
45, 26, 27, 30, 9, 5, 7, 10, 9, 12, 37, 19, 21, 5, 49, 23, 58, 
85, 24, 4, 12, 9, 9, 6, 6, 4, 10, 8, 7, 45, 20, 23, 9, 15, 7, 
6, 10, 14, 28, 44, 23, 37, 71, 61, 45, 19, 22, 10, 16, 23, 37, 
20, 24, 14, 10, 29, 23, 16, 25, 17, 15, 25, 31, 18, 45, 21, 14, 
17, 16, 30, 27, 13, 22, 11, 6, 8, 26, 15, 28, 23, 22, 34, 9, 
19, 6, 6, 21, 22, 9, 8, 25, 22, 23, 16, 9, 10.3000885358035, 
10.5680273254464, 10.8359661150893, 9, 25, 34, 24, 22.3425541619896, 
21, 10, 8, 17, 17, 27, 13, 27, 19, 32, 18, 18, 18, 13, 28, 24, 
12, 47, 23, 22, 26, 31, 19, 17, 19, 32, 15, 12, 4, 18, 10, 12, 
12, 19, 14, 6, 13, 18, 26, 31, 40, 7, 4, 28, 54, 27, 52, 20, 
9, 38, 43, 36, 4, 13, 29, 32, 43, 17, 23, 36, 21, 28, 20, 38, 
42, 25, 24, 50, 45, 24, 6, 10, 10, 13, 12, 14, 24, 19, 34, 51, 
28, 15, 14, 11, 10, 44, 29, 33, 46, 54, 56, 36, 41, 55, 29, 37, 
64, 41, 43, 85, 72, 58, 119, 72, 11, 5, 17, 23, 78, 64, 17, 47, 
31, 62, 101, 72, 59, 35, 17, 15, 56, 49, 45, 77, 79, 33, 20, 
81, 54, 30, 54, 64, 49, 81, 68, 35, 65, 130, 70, 55, 35, 11, 
10, 90, 28, 28, 17, 31, 89, 85, 29, 52, 34, 28, 32, 54, 61, 48, 
33, 36, 71, 58, 131, 67, 34, 75, 136, 95, 46, 138, 170, 192, 
209, 119, 147, 136, 131, 181, 127, 182, 216, 168, 159, 161, 140, 
98, 33, 62, 128, 135, 102, 25, 5, 22, 18, 9, 82, 82, 48, 11, 
29, 20, 6, 10, 30, 63, 169, 163, 218, 122, 81, 19, 13, 59, 19, 
45, 19, 15, 15, 48, 34, 118, 83, 42, 84, 12, 14, 11, 14, 11, 
6, 49, 64, 14, 8, 24, 11, 8, 26, 8, 22, 41, 32, 18, 21, 43, 88, 
74, 101, 71, 9, 30, 55, 18, 16, 10, 32, 10, 6, 6, 7, 9, 32, 73, 
67, 76, 25, 71, 52, 34, 46, 60, 48, 32, 111, 54, 64, 37, 26, 
5, 6, 35, 8, 12, 49, 25, 23, 17, 60, 39, 37, 10, 7, 12, 52, 47, 
87, 43, 63, 49, 25, 39, 34, 36, 24, 14, 11, 15, 2, 9, 12, 23, 
17, 6, 5, 3, 9, 16, 17, 9, 11, 7, 23, 54, 40, 55, 32, 19, 12, 
5, 18, 12, 26, 10, 15, 15, 5, 7, 10, 13, 11, 8, 7, 7, 9, 12, 
11, 21, 15, 10, 6, 16, 17, 10, 22, 35, 10, 16, 12, 25, 17, 22, 
28, 8, 7, 14, 22, 15, 10, 12, 5, 11, 20, 13, 11, 17, 31, 17, 
4, 19, 11, 15, 18, 20, 22, 7, 6, 13, 14, 17, 21, 8, 6, 32, 33, 
49, 54, 31, 5, 3, 23, 26, 16, 19, 29, 16, 9, 16, 11, 10, 24, 
6, 3, 4, 18, 23, 9, 18, 29, 13, 4, 24, 12, 6, 13, 7, 12, 21, 
18, 10, 23, 14, 12, 22, 20, 24, 21, 30, 31, 25, 11, 8, 38, 28, 
30, 16, 28, 26, 15, 17, 31, 20, 17, 24, 27, 12, 50, 26, 19, 27, 
25, 40, 15, 23, 31, 45, 43, 57, 19, 17, 56, 86, 39, 50, 42, 32, 
15, 50, 25, 31, 24, 38, 28, 8, 10, 20, 27, 46, 84, 84, 63, 158, 
129, 86, 111, 174, 96, 117, 121, 124.914045638056, 127, 152, 
117, 88, 41, 27, 10, 12, 48, 19, 12, 23, 35, 39, 19, 75, 17, 
10, 6, 29, 81, 119, 116, 106, 85, 48, 120, 96, 64, 53, 45, 48, 
67, 59, 77, 84, 46, 84, 63, 67, 84, 160, 168, 241, 170, 44, 30, 
46.1503142732202, 56.8550224709276, 67.5597306686349, 78.2644388663423, 
88.9691470640496, 99.673855261757, 110.378563459464, 121.083271657172, 
131.787979854879, 148, 111, 166, 93, 9, 51, 160, 191, 160, 221, 
201, 177, 207, 161, 197, 199, 193, 151, 180, 162, 128, 105, 50, 
14, 43, 36, 59, 96, 47, 35, 153, 101, 62, 211, 155, 136, 67, 
10, 6, 5, 15, 17, 18, 23, 41, 73, 37, 45, 47, 51, 83, 65, 8, 
8, 19, 24, 35, 81, 57, 18, 33, 13, 11, 11, 23, 45, 47, 10, 34, 
56, 63, 46, 113, 98, 50, 102, 113, 101, 86, 51, 24, 16, 53, 30, 
35, 14, 22, 20, 21, 49, 26, 19, 28, 71, 54, 25, 46, 57, 35, 22, 
35, 18, 18, 20, 29, 17, 28, 23, 22, 12, 23, 31, 27, 21, 21, 32, 
12, 33, 23, 13, 39, 46, 9, 10, 17, 34, 13, 38, 9, 19, 13, 34, 
7, 27, 49, 11, 41, 39, 50, 42, 53, 41, 9, 12, 32, 20, 17, 16, 
16, 18, 10, 9, 15, 17, 21, 31, 23, 12, 8, 21, 26, 18, 8, 21, 
23, 8, 20, 13, 21, 21, 10, 11, 5, 13, 16, 18, 31, 19, 32, 10, 
22, 15, 14, 27, 33, 16, 16, 35, 24, 22, 28, 15, 9, 23, 38, 48, 
29, 30, 42, 10, 11, 32, 31, 19, 27, 14, 6, 7, 22, 29, 19, 19, 
12, 10, 7, 11, 17, 12, 20, 16, 10, 26, 22, 25, 30, 46, 47, 13, 
19, 19, 31, 25, 9, 7, 6, 6, 12, 12, 26, 43, 25, 5, 4, 5, 32, 
19, 44, 61, 12, 8, 32, 43, 16, 17, 14, 12, 8, 23, 24, 33, 29, 
46, 40, 5, 7, 11, 7, 15, 50, 41, 33, 40, 39, 25, 52, 60, 73, 
45, 25, 31, 17, 47, 12, 35, 20, 14, 9, 53, 73, 109, 49, 15, 32, 
82, 79, 95, 133, 64, 47, 75, 50, 82, 117, 161, 129, 68, 42, 20, 
10, 63, 142, 55, 16, 23, 30, 81, 113, 168, 145, 96, 111, 189, 
205, 175, 151, 87, 106, 168, 159, 216, 197, 108, 23, 13, 60, 
120, 11, 173, 108, 77, 110, 196, 235, 215, 201, 229, 152, 103, 
106, 76, 152, 130, 85, 35, 107, 86, 161, 195, 215, 200, 164, 
96, 161, 177, 177, 158, 121, 97, 101, 70, 43, 32, 55), .Tsp = c(1, 
6.9972602739726, 365), class = "ts")
```

Comment: what is the frequency of data, daily, hourly or something else?

Comment: I have daily data for about 7 years. Starts Jan 01 of year x and ends Dec 31 of that year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using appropriate decomposition methods for daily data. Since it can have multiple seasonality. As an example, following seasonality can be observed in daily data:

1. Day of the week.
2. Day of the month.
3. Month of the year.
4. Holidays/special events.

All of the above should be accounted. Using `decompose` in `R` does not capture above. `tbats` in `forecast` package can do multi seasonal time series. Below is the seasonal decomposition using `tbats` with two seasonal period.

```
> Data.msts <- msts(Data,seasonal.periods = c(7,365)) #multi seasonal time series
> fit <- tbats(Data.msts)
> plot(fit)
> plot(fit$errors)
```

[image]

Error plot, shows no pattern at least visually and also using `acf` on errors `acf(fit$errors)`.

[image]

This is just an example. you can use other techniques such as unobserved components model that can handle multi seasonality and also add external regressors such as holidays.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know of the TBATS before. Regarding this model. I want to use a combination of these time series models as inputs to a multivariate time series model. Before I was just feeding in the `observed` data but I know this is wrong since (as you see in the data here) it has seasonality. What would I use now as my "time series" data?

Comment: Do you have an example on how I can add external regressors such as holidays?